How can I access subsets in manageable chunks?
I have a large subset (as an example).
subset = Subsets[Range[8000], {2}]

I cannot evaluate this as I don't have enough space.
So the question is how can I access the subset in chunks of, say, 100,000 elements each so I can process them one at a time?
Something like subset[[1]] would give me subsets from 1 to 100,000 or something similar.

The general approach in such cases is something called "lazy evaluation". Mathematica doesn't yet have this well integrated, but there are several implementations available. For example: How can I correctly use LazySubsets from Wolfram's Lazy package?. Do those answers work for you?
